# Get Data from Parameter in React Native and Pass it to Properties

Tags: react-native

i want to get **index value** from this **renderItem**, and pass it to **onSwipeableOpen properties**. how to do this? every time i test using this code

> onSwipeableOpen={() =>  console.warn(index) }
>   this code i get undefined result.

```
renderItem = ({ item, index, drag, isActive }) => {
    return (
      <Swipeable
        ref={this.updateRef}
        friction={2}
        leftThreshold={30}
        rightThreshold={40}
        renderRightActions={this.renderRightActions}
        onSwipeableOpen={() =>  console.warn(index) }
      >
```

Comment: Your code is correct. Did you try checking the data you passed into data property?

Comment: which library are you using for renderItem?

Comment: @KhangTran i did use console.warn to check but unfornutately it return null

Comment: @GauravRoy i use swipeable from react native gesture handler